# Bluetooth stops working after using HDMI audio output

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, hdmi

I have been unable to hear anything from my rasberryPi4 out of my wireless headphones just after I used the HDMI port on my monitor (which also stopped working at the same time).
I know that the issue is not my wireless headphones, as they work just fine with my phone. They *do* connect, but they don't output any sound. I also know that the issue is probably bluetooth itself, as the same happenes for *all* bluetooth devices; connects, but produces no sound. I can't hear any sound from any source, video, audio, or application.

Reseting the rasberryPi fixes this problem, but I also lose all of my files. I don't want to be transfering files from USB to rasberryPi and back again every time I want to use SonicPi (which can't use bluetooth).

---

How do I get sound output to my wireless headphones?

Comment: From what you have wrote it appears the audio out is switching the whatever audio device was added last. If you are on the desktop, have you clicked on the "Settings" button on the top right? (I haven't used the desktop for a while so it may have moved)

Comment: @ukBaz for whatever reason, the "Bluetooth Settings" option is greyed out and connot be clicked.